# How to build a real time recommendation engine with good performance?

Tags: python, html

I am a data analyst and just assigned to build a real time recommendation engine for our website.

I need to analyse the visitor behavior and do real time analysis for those input. Thus I have three questions about this project.

1) Users are not forced to sign-up. Is there any methodology to capture user behavior such as search and visit history?

2) The recommendation models can be pre-trained but the prediction process takes time. How can we improve the performance?

3) I only know how to write Python Scripts. How can I implement the recommendation engine with my python scripts?

Thanks.

===============

However, 90% of our customers purchase the products during their first visit and will not come back shortly. 
We cannot make a ready model for new visitors. 
And they prefer to use itemCF for the recommendation engine. 
It sounds like a mission impossible now...

Comment: This is too broad for SO. What code have you tried/written so far?

Comment: Actually I was assigned to make a project proposal and send it to our IT vendors. My current job duty is mainly for write analytics reports with jupyter notebook thus I totally do not have any idea how to work out a web application.

Comment: Thanks. I have implement apache storm to fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question however I will do my best to answer:

Visit history can be tracked by enabling some form of analytics tracking on your domain. This can either be a pre-built solution that you implement and will provide a detailed overview of all visitors to your domain, usually with some form of dashboard. Most pre-built solutions provide a way to obtain the analytics that have been collected.

Another way would be to use browser cookies to store information pertaining to each visit to your domain and their search/page history. This information will be available to the website whenever the user visits it within the same browser. When the user visits your website, you could send the information to a server/rest endpoint which could analyse information (I.P/geolocation/number of visits/search/page history) and make recommendation based on that. Another common method is to track past purchases ect.

To improve performance one solution would be to always have the prediction model for a particular user ready for when they next visit the site. That way, there is no delay. However, the first time a user visits you likely wont have enough information to make detailed predictions so you will have to resort to providing options based on geolocation (which shouldn't take to long and wont impact performance)

There is another approach that can be taken and above mainly talked about making predictions based on a users behavior browsing the website. Content-based filtering is another approach which will recommend things that are similar to a item that the user is currently viewing. This approach is generally easier, as it just requires that you query a database for items that are similar in category, purpose/use ect.

There is no getting around using javascript for the client side stuff, however your recommendation engine can be built in Python (it could be a simple REST api endpoint with access to the items database). Most people use flask,django or eve to implement REST API's in Python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
However, 90% of our customers purchase the products during their first visit and will not come back shortly. We cannot make a ready model for new visitors. And they prefer to use itemCF for the recommendation enginer. It sounds like a mission impossible now...